NASM how to run assembly in vscode
I'm interested in learning about compilers by experimenting with assembly language in Visual Studio Code (VSCode). However, I've encountered difficulties setting up an environment to run assembly code. Can someone provide guidance on configuring VSCode for assembly language development and recommend tools or extensions? Additionally, if anyone has expertise in compiler construction, I would appreciate insights on getting started with building a compiler from scratch

What have you tried already? Which tutorial are you following? Did it work?

If you're interested in digging into compilers and asm (and kudos for that) - why in the world are you trying to do this in a heavily abstracted (bloated) IDE, especially where plugins are concerned?  My two cents would be to kick it old school, see and understand what's actually going on (what hasn't been abstracted away) and open a terminal, and start there.

Aside, it might be easier to start with ARM rather than x86-64; due to the simplified (reduced) instruction set.  Robert Plantz's online book Introduction to Computer Organization provides an excellent, detailed and well explained tutorial for learning ARM asm.  There isn't an IDE in sight. Write, compile and run all from the terminal.
